# xquartz: couldn't query security extension and xterm failing

Tags: ssh, osx-lion, x11, xterm, xauth

I am using OSX 10.7.5 from my MacBook Air to login to remote Linux workstation, running Suse (/etc/issue: SUSE Linux Enterprise Desktop 11 SP2  (x86_64) - Kernel \r (\l))

Everything was working fine until I started to play with macports latest X11, XQuartz XWindow System (XQuartz 2.7.4 (xorg-server 1.13.0)). By default OSX 10.7.5 comes with XQuartz 2.6.4 (xorg-server 1.10.6), however I've installed and made default XQuartz 2.7.4. I am now observing two issues:

(1) When logging to my remote Suse box (this is done via VPN tunnel btw, not sure if it matters), via 'user1> ssh -X user2@wks01' I am getting

Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated

This (at least appears) to be traced to the fact that there's no 'Security' extension on the new Xquarts server. Traced via ssh -vvv option, and then due to the fact that xauth is failing, so running it separately on MacBox, or remote Suse gives:

user2@wks04:~> xauth generate "$DISPLAY" .
trustedxauth: (argv):1:  couldn't query Security extension on display "localhost:10.0"

'ssh -Y' logs in without warning

(2) What is also interesting, that in both ssh modes -X and -Y I am able to open and forward to my display any X-application that I have checked, including xclock, xlogo, xcalc and even eclipse. However running simple 'xterm' results in a hanging job (i.e. appears running), but xterm never displays on my Mac.

While rolling back to will XQuartz 2.6.4 probably help with the issues above (as all the above operations worked smoothly before), but I am curious now to understand the root of the matter.

Thank you in advance for your help,
Dmitry

Comment: can you start xterm with xtrace and show x requests dump? e.i `xtrace & ; DISPLAY=:9 xterm`

Comment: Hi Andrey, I am getting:

Comment: Hi Andrey, I am getting:
$ slogin -X user2@wks \n
Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated \n
wks:~> xtrace & ; DISPLAY=:9 xterm – \n
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;' \n
wks:~> xtrace /usr/bin/xterm \n
Function   File              Line \n
------------------------------------------------------ \n

nothing was happening and then xtrace window and then xterm window appeared on my Mac X11, after 5 minutes. I was not patient enough before. However, I see nothing from xtrace - Can you please advise how to use xtrace correctly?

Comment: struggling with text formatting on this forum - '\n' characters mean 'new-line' in my previous comment

Comment: you are probably using different xtrace (the name is confusing and ambiguious). Download and install from source: http://xtrace.alioth.debian.org/ then start xtrace in shell with forwarded X11 and your program in another shell ith DISPLAY pointed to xtrace's (by default it's :9)

Comment: I've managed to install a correct xtrace and make a dump. It is almost 1mb big, no obvious errors. What shall I look for in it?

Comment: `QueryExtension` and `SECURITY` Can you post gist with ~20 lines before and after QueryExtension?